# Adding XML element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have been working on adding XML element to XML structure without success, here is my code.

```
var parseXml;
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
            return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
            };
        }
        else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
            parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
                var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = "false";
                xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
                return xmlDoc;
            };
        }
        else {
            parseXml = function() { return null; }
        }
        var xmlTree = parseXml("<root></root>");

        function add_children(child_name,parent_name)
        {
            str = '<'+child_name+'></'+child_name+'>';
            //strXML = parseXml(str);
            $(xmlTree).find(parent_name).append(str);
            var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlTree);
            console.log(xmlString);
        }
        add_children("apple","root");
        add_children("orange","root");
        add_children("lychee","root");
```

but console is showing `<root/>` all three times

Comment: Try parsing the string with the `$.parseXML()`, which returns an jQuery object that can be traversed an processed with jQuery

Comment: Sorry, `$.parseXML` does not return a jQuery object, returns a document that can be passed to jQuery `$()`

Comment: @davids changed as u told but getting this error. HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy
fragment.appendChild( script );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the node in the Html `document`, not in the XML one, so you can't append it. Change this line:

```
str = '<'+child_name+'></'+child_name+'>';
```

For this one:

```
str = xmlTree.createElement(child_name);
```

See the working code in http://jsfiddle.net/W9Wpb/

Comment: i have one more query how to get the count of number of descendents of an element in jquery ? $(xmlTree).children(parent_name).length is giving me children count

Comment: You want to get just the number of the first level of descendants, don't you? In that case `$(xmlTree).find(parent_name).children().length`

Comment: i want to get all the descendents starting from that element till the leaf elements not only the first level of descendents

Comment: So `$(xmlTree).find(parent_name).find('*').length`. `children()` will look up just in the first level of descendants, `find` in all of them

Comment: thanks once again man...for quick solutions you are of great help for me.

Comment: No worries, maybe some day you'll be the one who helps me :)